# Visual Studio 2015 RC cant/wont connect to Githib Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In Team Explorer I can choose to connect to GitHib or Github Enterprise.  However, when I try to connect to enterprise it just says 'Could not connect to the server'.  It's very quick to say this so I'm pretty sure it's not a timeout.

Has anyone got this to work?

Ok thanks for the downvote, but I have already done web searches and could not find anything, not even on StackOverflow.  This was only released today so there's not likely to be much information available.

Comment: Sounds like a networking problem.

Answer (score 2):

Upvoted...Getting a similar problem connecting to Github in VS2015 RC Team Explorer manage connections. I can connect to github through web and github desktop. Had a quick poke around for any settings that may be relevant but nothing jumps out at me. The can't connect message does come back very quickly, made me think it was a password problem to start with.

Got it working. Even though I was sure I selected Github in the initial installation I tried installing the github visual studio add-in (ghfvs.msi) separately and it works.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not gong mad!  I guess this is why they do RC's.

Answer (score 0):

So I installed the `Visual Studio 2015 RTM` today. I made sure I checked the `GitHub` plugin during the install.

Opened Visual Studio and typed in the correct Username, Password and GitHub Enterprise URL and the login button stayed in a disabled state :(

I re-downloaded and installed the plugin [here](https://visualstudio.github.com/) and it started working for me :)

Comment: Well that helped a little thanks. Before it was saying it couldnt connect.  Now it just says login failed.  Sigh...